# JavaScript storing variable numeric value as cookie or session

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, session-cookies, shopping-cart

How do I store a variable that will hold a total as a cookie or any method that will store the data even after the page load. I have a JavaScript exercise where the user selects items and then they're total is displayed. Once their total is displayed they have to enter how they will be paying (meaning the amount). I then want to return their change amount. This is why I need the total variable value to be stored after the page loads. Below is my code.

var shoppingItems = {
        "Stainless Steel Cooking Pot": 29.99,
        "Mini Stainless Steel Blender": 19.99,
        "Kitchen Towel Set": 7.99,
        "Large Tan Coffee Mug": 5.49,
        "5 Round Dinner Plate Set": 5.99,
        "Salt and Pepper Shaker Set": 1.99,
        "Large Blue Broom": 3.98,
        "Pink Soap Dish": 2.50,
        "Silver Bathroom Trash Can": 6.99,
        "Silk Black Bathroom Robe": 9.99,
      };

```
  var itemsSelectedValues = [];
  var total = 0;
  function listOfCheckedItems(catalogToLookFrom) {
    var yourItemsPurchased = $("input:checkbox:checked");
    for (i = 0; i < yourItemsPurchased.length; i++) {
         itemsSelectedValues.push(yourItemsPurchased[i].value);
    } // line closes for loop
    console.log(itemsSelectedValues);
    for (i = 0; i < itemsSelectedValues.length; i++) {
      total = total + catalogToLookFrom[itemsSelectedValues[i]];
    } // closes for loop
    document.getElementById("yourPurchase").innerHTML = "Your items purchased <strong>" + itemsSelectedValues + "</strong> came to a total of <br/><strong>$" + total + "</strong>";
  } // line closes listOfCheckedItems function

  function getOrderTotal() {
    listOfCheckedItems(shoppingItems);
  }
```

//////////  All of this code above works. However the var total variable is what I need to be a cookie or some type of JavaScript session variable.

This code below is where I calculate the user total and why I need variable total numeric value to be saved. I need to be able to subtract the amount the user paid with, with their products total. Can someone please help me?

```
  function whatUserPaidWith() {
    var amountUserPaid = $("#amountPaid").val();
    var customerChange = amountUserPaid - total;
    document.getElementById("displayUserChange").innerHTML = "You paid <strong>" + amountUserPaid + "</strong> your change due is <strong>" + customerChange + "</strong>";

  }
```

HTML Code
  Select Your Items, Then Checkout at the Cash Register

**Select 1 or more items to purchase at the register**

Department Store Items

Stainless Steel Cooking Pot - $29.99
    Mini Stainless Steel Blender - $19.99
    Kitchen Towel Set - $7.99
    Large Tan Coffee Mug - $5.49
    5 Round Dinner Plate Set - $5.99
    Salt and Pepper Shaker Set - $1.99
    Large Blue Broom - $3.98
    Pink Soap Dish - $2.5
    Silver Bathroom Trash Can - $6.99
    Silk Black Bathroom Robe - $9.99
    
    
    Submit

How will you be paying for your purchase?

Please enter the amount below that you're paying.

Enter Amount Total: 
    
    
    Submit

Comment: why not you use localStorage instead of a cookie?

Comment: @simplelenz How do I use localStorage?

Answer (score 1):

you can persist values in a session using the [sessionStorage api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage).

to do this, just add your variable as a property on the `sessionStorage` object:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('totalNumericValue ', 300);
```

to access the value later, you can do so by referencing the property:

```
sessionStorage.getItem('totalNumericValue')
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Here's my new code now but I'm getting an error message:

Comment: Error message says:  Uncaught referenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Comment: instead of sessionStorage use localStorage. Because sessionStorage data will not persist if you open a link in a new tab but localStorage will persist.

Comment: a "JavaScript session variable" was specifically asked for in the question. It is not wise to automatically choose the most persistent option.

Comment: @aishah91 you should not be doing any assignment when using session storage. if you update your code with what you now have, i can provide some further pointers

Comment: I'll send it in another question